# How to remove column header in csv output in BI publisher?

Tags: oracle, csv, rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

Hi I want to create a report in bi publisher which is

- csv format
- uses semicolon as the delimiter
- no column header

Note that the  report is scheduled.

I always get the data like this

```
GL_ACCOUNT_CODE;GL_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION;REPORTING_CODE;REPORTING_DESCRIPTION;ACCOUNT_TYPE;START_DATE;END_DATE
208000;"SITES INTERNET";208000;"208000 desctest";Asset;;
101000;CAPITAL;;;"Owner's Equity";;
218300;"MATERIEL DE BUREAU ET INFO. ST DENIS";;;Asset;;
205000;"CONCESSIONS ET DROITS SIMILAIRES";;;Asset;;
```

but i just want the data, not the column headers, like this

```
    208000;"SITES INTERNET";208000;"208000 desctest";Asset;;
    101000;CAPITAL;;;"Owner's Equity";;
    218300;"MATERIEL DE BUREAU ET INFO. ST DENIS";;;Asset;;
    205000;"CONCESSIONS ET DROITS SIMILAIRES";;;Asset;;
```

I tried to use an eText template, but it only returns 0's and question marks. Can you please analyze my template. Thank you.

```
Format Setup:

<TEMPLATE TYPE> DELIMITER_BASED
<OUTPUT CHARACTER SET>  iso-8859-1
<NEW RECORD CHARACTER>  Carriage Return


Format Data Records:

<LEVEL> DATA_DS
<NEW RECORD>    G_1
<MAXIMUM LENGTH>    <FORMAT>    <DATA>  <COMMENTS>
99  Number  ‘GL_ACCOUNT_CODE’

1   Alpha   `;` Delimiter
99  Alpha   ‘GL_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION’

1   Alpha   `;` Delimiter
99  Alpha   ‘ACCOUNT_TYPE’

1   Alpha   `;` Delimiter
99  Number  ‘REPORTING_DESCRIPTION’

1   Alpha   `;` Delimiter
<END LEVEL> G_1

<END LEVEL> DATA_DS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **eText** template to achieve your requirement. See documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_etext_tmpl.htm#BIPRD2908

Comment: Hi, I put my eText template above, can you please analyze it. Thank you.

Comment: Test your eText template using Template viewer. (https://ioraclefusion.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/testing-etext-templates/) Also you may provide sample XML.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we're using right now, and all we don't get the data, just zeroes and question marks.

Comment: The template viewer log will show you what the error is.Check that and post the message. Also you may provide sample XML to further look into your template design.

Comment: Thanks for that. I now get the data that I want :) However, I'm creating a scheduled report. Is there a way to schedule output from template builder and also the report must be in csv format.Hope you can help me on this. Thanks :)

Comment: Of course you can schedule the report, but from the BI publisher scheduler page. Create the data model and the report, for the report template you use your Etext template.